# Visual Basic C# with Selenium variable in css selector

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

I am only a week or so into C#, but thanks to forums like this I am able to piece together a bunch of code and get a general understanding. However, I have a problem with using a variable I can't solve.

```
List<IWebElement> elementList = new List<IWebElement>();
elementList.AddRange(browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class^='CalendarDays-calendarDays-']>div:nth-child(3)>div>div[class^='CalendarEvent-event-']")));
int t = elementList.Count;

for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
{
    var item + i = browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class^='CalendarDays-calendarDays-']>div:nth-child(3)>div>div:nth-child(i)>div>div[class^='CalendarEvent-title']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
}
```

Problems are "var item + i" and "div:nth-child(i)". The first is automatically creating sequential variables and the second trying to get the nth-child using the variable "i". I can't figure out how to format "i" in either instance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Working Code after edits:

```
List<IWebElement> elementList = new List<IWebElement>();
elementList.AddRange(browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class^='CalendarDays-calendarDays-']>div:nth-child(3)>div>div[class^='CalendarEvent-event-']")));
int t = elementList.Count;

List<String> listItems = new List<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
{
    String item = browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class^='CalendarDays-calendarDays-']>div:nth-child(3)>div>div:nth-child(i)>div>div[class^='CalendarEvent-title']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
    listItems.Add(item);
}
```

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a list to store the different items, you have to know the type of `GetAttribute`. I assume it is `String` :

```
List<String> listItems = new List<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
{
    String item = browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class^='CalendarDays-calendarDays-']>div:nth-child(3)>div>div:nth-child(i)>div>div[class^='CalendarEvent-title']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
    listItems.Add(item);
}
```

then you can access the list items by index `listItems[i]`

For the second part of the question you have to concatenate the string with the i of the for loop like this:

```
browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class^='CalendarDays-calendarDays-']>div:nth-child(3)>div>div:nth-child("+i+")>div>div[class^='CalendarEvent-title']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
```

Comment: The second part works perfectly. However I couldn't get the first to work as shown. I used var item = new Object[t]; and then when i use item[i] I gets an Index was ouside the bounds of the array error.

Comment: You are right. I was confused and thought it was Javascript. For dynamically adding object you have to use a list. I will edit my answer

Comment: I get this as you wrote: Error CS0820 Cannot initialize an implicitly-typed variable with an array initializer

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was just reading up on lists yesterday for the counting of the elements and got array stuck in  my head on this for some reason. I was on the wrong track. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `var item + i`. Just use the same variable each time, it's inside the loop scope anyway.

To insert the `i` variable to the locator you can use string interpolation

```
var item = browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"div[class^='CalendarDays-calendarDays-']>div:nth-child(3)>div>div:nth-child({i})>div>div[class^='CalendarEvent-title']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work and answers one of the two questions. I could use this and just write the information I am after to a file in the for loop, but I was also hoping to learn how to use an array as well for future use.